Configuring Darkice on Raspberry pi 4 with IOcrest USB Soundcard
I have had nothing but issues with 2 methods of trying to get my raspberry pi 4 to stream my RTL SDR audio over my network. I have tried 2 methods. The first was using XRDP and remote desktop on Windows. I created a new user for my pi but still had only a blue screen on RDP on my Windows client. I obtained display 10 errors or something of the sort although the logs mentioned successful connection, but as mentioned I only had a blue screen.
I ran into a roadblock on the second method when configuring my darkice streamer (icecast2 seems to work). I used aplay -l and arecord -l and though my device = hw:3,0 but I'm not sure. I also had continual issues with some pulseaudio file? I attached the darkice.cfg file and the errors I experienced when running sudo darkice -c ~/darkice.cfg
Any help is appreciated

https://scarygliders.net/2012/04/06/get-audio-with-your-xrdpx11rdp-connections-lan-or-remote/
https://chipsandbitsworkshop.wordpress.com/2018/04/08/quick-guide-to-live-audio-stream-with-icecast2-and-darkice/

darkice.cfg
[general]
duration        = 0      # duration in s, 0 forever
bufferSecs      = 5      # buffer, in seconds
reconnect       = yes    # reconnect if disconnected
no_pulseaudio   = 1

[input]
#device          = plughw:1,0 # Soundcard device for the audio input
device          = hw:3,0
#device         = default 
sampleRate      = 44100   # sample rate 11025, 22050 or 44100
bitsPerSample   = 16      # bits
channel         = 2       # 2 = stereo

[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr       # constant bit rate ('cbr' constant, 'abr' average)
#quality         = 1.0       # 1.0 is best quality (use only with vbr)
format          = mp3       # format. Choose 'vorbis' for OGG Vorbis
bitrate         = 320       # bitrate
server          = localhost # or IP
port            = 8000      # port for IceCast2 access
password        = hackme    # source password for the IceCast2 server
mountPoint      = myMountPoint
#rapi.mp3  # mount point on the IceCast2 server .mp3 or .ogg
name            = Raspberry Pi

Errors from running sudo darkice -c ~/darkice.cfg
DarkIce 1.3 live audio streamer, http://code.google.com/p/darkice/
Copyright (c) 2000-2007, Tyrell Hungary, http://tyrell.hu/
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Akos Maroy and Rafael Diniz
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it 
under the terms of The GNU General Public License version 3 or
any later version.

Using config file: /home/ubuntu/darkice.cfg
Using ALSA DSP input device: sysdefault
Using POSIX real-time scheduling, priority 4
ALSA lib conf.c:4002:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so (/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
DarkIce: DarkIce.cpp:1273: can't open connector [0]

